# Magento 2.4 - changing CSS

Tags: css, magento2.4, luma-theme

I want to change the menu bar and some other elements on the luma theme for Magento.

I have not found a way to do this yet, anyone knows how to do it?

Any tips and help is appreciated

-JP

Answer (score 0):

If Your using the by creating child theme then create the CSS folder under the

```
MAGENTOROOT/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEMEMODULE/YOURTHEME/web/css/style.css
```

And add the css file in head in the **default_head_blocks.xml**

```
MAGENTOROOT/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEMEMODULE/YOURTHEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

Code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <!-- ADD CSS  -->
            <css src="css/css-custom.css" />
        </head> 
</page>
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the answer, do I need to create a registration.php? 

And if I create a child theme, will all the sample setup still be showing or will I lose that?

Comment: @Jan-petterHavna The Child theme will render at time of load if there is file it will take the content from you chid theme or it will take from parent theme, if you need to change any header content then you need to traverse where the header content renders in Parent theme then in that same format you need to put you header file into child theme and edit the header content, and Yes for creating the child theme you need to create the registration.php, theme.xml.